# alerta, obtener valor de confirmación vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Quiero hacer una alerta de confirmación y ejecutar códigos dependiendo de la acción que elija el usuario, hacer algo si da aceptar y si de cancelar hacer otra cosa, por ahora solo logro mostrar la alerta de confirmación con este código:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.Page, Me.GetType, "ConfirmaGestion", "confirm('Esta gestionando al 100 % , ¿desea continuar?');", True)
```

como capturo los valores de confirmación.

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [esta](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#getting-started) librería. Es muy útil y estética. Solo debes escribir el código en el callback y si deseas ejecutar algo del lado del servidor simplemente generas un __postaback. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Como estas llamando esta función js usando el método [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
"confirm('Esta gestionando al 100 % , ¿desea continuar?');"
```

puedes modificar la función `confirm()` para capturar el valor en caso de aceptar, esto se realizaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function confirm(mensaje) {
      var valorConfirmacion = window.prompt(mensaje);
      document.forms[0].confirmacion.value = valorConfirmacion; 
      document.forms[0].submit();  
   }
</script>
```

Agrega el campo "hidden" para el valor de "confirmacion" en la forma:

```
<input type="hidden" name="confirmacion" />
```

---

Encontré en el sitio en inglés esta pregunta similar:

[Retornar valor de ventana de confirmación usando ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243056/return-value-of-scriptmanager-registerstartupscript-confirm-box-in-code-behind)

Comment: pero Jorge el esta usando vb.net no js

Comment: @shadow es que en realidad usando VB.net esta llamando una función JS que muestra un texto : "confirm('Esta gestionando al 100 % , ¿desea continuar?');" y el OP desea obtener el valor de confirmación.

Comment: ummmm tienes razón, no puse suficiente atención  +1

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar algo como esto:

```
Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("Desea Grabar sus datos", "Guardar", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    MessageBox.Show("Cancelado")
ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
    MessageBox.Show("No grabados")
ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
    MessageBox.Show("datos grabados")
End If
```

en este caso muestro un mensaje en caso de que coloque Yes, No, Cancel... alli debes colocar la accion que deseas realizar...espero te sirva suerte..!!

**Referencia:** [Aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/050ae7a5-c9bb-400a-ba32-a238e022c51f/how-do-i-show-a-confirmation-box-instead-of-a-messagebox?forum=vblanguage)

Comment: Por lo que veo esta usando js. Esta desarrollando una web.

Comment: En realidad el OP esta desarrollando para web como comenta Fran, ya que esta usando el namespace System.Web.UI.